# Send HCI ACL Data packets with hcitool

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, hci

**History:**
I used BlueZ 5.43 to communicate with a bluetooth device:

1. `connect FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`
2. `select-attribute /org/bluez/hci/dev_ ...`
3. `write 0x54`

It takes some time, but it works.

**Current issue:**

Now I'm using the HCI commands defined in the Bluetooth Specification to connect to my device via `hcitool cmd ...`. Works fine.

But: I can't write an ACL Data packet via `hcitool cmd` to my connected device:

1. The ACL packet (see BT Core Spec Vol 2, Part E, 5.2.4) is sent with `sudo hcitool cmd 02 40 00 08 00 04 00 04 00 12 0D 00 54`
2. The `btmon` shows the error: `Unknown HCI Command`
3. Using `sudo hcidump --r` I see that the ACL packet is modified to `01 40 08 0B 00 08 00 04 00 04 00 12 0D 00 54`.

How can I send a ACL Data packet via `hcitool cmd`?

Thank you,
Tom